# Implicit conversion loses precision ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm getting a warning like
'**Implicit conversion loses integer precision long long to unsigned long**' at a this line of code

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [appdele.sharedArrays[j] defaultRepresentation];

Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
```

and below line give warning ''Implicit conversion loses integer precision long long to `NSInteger '` at a this line of code
'

```
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
```

how can i remove this warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of that method is:

```
- (NSUInteger)getBytes:(uint8_t *)buffer
            fromOffset:(long long)offset
                length:(NSUInteger)length
                 error:(NSError **)error
```

You are using `0.0` for the `offset` which is a literal `double`; instead use `0LL` which is a literal `long long`.

Also, for some unknown reason, the `ALAssetRepresentation.size` is `long long` but this method expect the `length` as `NSUInteger`, so a cast is required:

```
NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer
                         fromOffset:0LL
                             length:(NSUInteger)rep.size
                              error:nil];
```

Comment: i tried your code but its still giving me same warning at length:rep.size. the variable j declared in shared arrays[j] is int.

Comment: @user2728950 OK fixed.